# colpick js color palletee position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, color-picker

I have used colpick.js to get a color pallet.
When i click the div it works fine. It opens the color box.
But when i scroll the page keeping the box open it wont scroll with the page.It always keep it postion in the scrolled area. simply it comes up and down with the scroll. Can someone help.

```
$(".colorCircle").colpick({
                color: '#212125',
                colorScheme: 'dark',
                layout: 'hex',
                submit: 0,
                onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb, el, bySetColor) {
                    $(el).css('background-color', '#' + hex);
                    $(el).attr('colCode', '#' + hex);
                    $(el).value = "";
                }
            }).keyup(function () {

                $(this).colpickSetColor(this.value);

            });
```

Comment: It's CSS probably says `position: fixed;`. Try changing that to `position: absolute;`. Or don't worry about this edge case.

Answer (score 0):

In your `colpick.css` ensure that the `.colpick` class has the `position` attribute set as `position: absolute;` if not set it. Just in case if it has already has this, then check your other CSS files where you may probably override this style.

The `colpick` library's `.colpick` class normally looks like,

```
.colpick {
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing:content-box;
    width: 346px;
    height: 170px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    direction:ltr;
    background:#ebebeb;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;

    /*Prevents selecting text when dragging the selectors*/
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Hope this helps!